# Run google scripts before html page load

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am creating a dashboard that is based on google scripts which pulls data from spreadsheet.

But my page loads before the JavaScript runs.

here is my code :-

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(chartData).loadCdata();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(otherChart).loadCdata();

  });
```

Since I will advance further and a lot more data has to be pulled from server side and I want html to only load "view" after my scripts finish

I have two questions:
1. In current scenario how can I make my html to print after my script runs.
2. how can I prevent loading data array again and again from server side. I just want to run it once and use the array data in different functions. "`.loadCdata();`"

this image shows only half of my chart is printed [image: only half chart is printing]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the main div and then display it after the server-side data has loaded.

```
<div id="main" style="display:none">
.... content
</div>

<script>
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.display = "block";
 }).loadData();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To display HTML after the server script completes, start off by having the HTML hidden (e.g. `display: none`) and then have your `chartData()` function change the display attribute so it becomes visible. (You can use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to make sure it happens in the correct sequence.)
2. Use the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) to save your array data in the browser storage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart1" style="display:none">
      <!-- Chart 1 -->
    </div>
    <div id="chart2" style="display:none">
      <!-- Chart 2 -->
    </div>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateCharts).loadCdata();
      });

      /**
       * Populate the charts, make them visible, and save data to sessionStorage for later usage.
       */
      function populateCharts(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          // Populate charts

          resolve();
        }).then(() => {
          // Make the charts visible
          document.getElementById("chart1").style.display = "block";
          document.getElementById("chart2").style.display = "block";

          // Save chart data to session storage
          sessionStorage.setItem("chartData", JSON.stringify(data));
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```